# Return the first number which occurs only once in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, nsarray

I would like to know what's the best or most appropriate approach for this question: Given a list of numbers example [2, 3, 4, 2, 3], return the first number that occurs only once in the list.

I have followed some algorithms approach and came up with this, but not sure if there are any built-in helper functions in Objective-C that will allow me to do this with a better performance..

If there are not built-ins solutions, is there is any improvements that can be made to my approach or any other solution that could be better in terms of performance?

**This is my updated solution for this:**
**For testing:**

```
#import "NSArray+Addons.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray<NSNumber *> *array = @[@(2), @(7), @(3), @(2), @(3), @(2), @(7), @(3), @(2), @(3), @(4), @(7), @(5), @(5), @(9)];
    NSLog(@"Unique number: %@", [array firstUniqueNumber]);
}

@end
```

**NSArray category:**

```
#import "NSArray+Addons.h"
#import "NSMutableDictionary+Addons.h"

@implementation NSArray (Addons)

- (NSNumber *)firstUniqueNumber
{
    if (!self.count)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber *, NSNumber *> *myUniqueNumbers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    return [myUniqueNumbers uniqueValueFromArray:self];
}

@end
```

**NSMutableDictionary category:**

```
#import "NSMutableDictionary+Addons.h"

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (Addons)

- (NSNumber *)uniqueValueFromArray:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)array
{
    if (!array.count)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    for (NSNumber *number in array)
    {
        if (!self[number])
        {
            self[number] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
        }
        else
        {
            NSInteger count = [self[number] integerValue];
            count++;
            self[number] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:count];
        }
    }

    return [self uniqueNumberWithArray:array];
}


- (NSNumber *)uniqueNumberWithArray:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)array
{
    if (!array.count)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSNumber *uniqueNumber = nil;

    for (NSInteger index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--)
    {
        NSNumber *key = array[index];

        if (self[key] && [self[key] integerValue] == 1)
        {
            uniqueNumber = key;
        }
    }

    return uniqueNumber;
}

@end
```

Comment: There won't be a built-in solution to this, as it's not a common requirement, so a bespoke solution is the only way.

Comment: @trojanfoe oh really? would you suggest any improvements to my approach? Are there any cases that my approach would crash? or fail returning the number?

Comment: I don't think your scheme will work if there are two non-repeated numbers.  Of if a number is repeated 3 times.

Comment: I cannot say I am fully clear how your approach even works.  Have you tested it?  Does it work for `0`?

Comment: @NorthBlast: your algorithm is bogus. For example if the numbers are `@[2,2,2,5]` your algorithm will return `@7` and not `@5`. It will not crash, however. And it cannot be improved, it's just wrong... Sorry..

Comment: I just tested with 0 and it returns 0. Which, I think is good because is the only value in the list. @trojanfoe

Comment: @Michael could suggest a better way? or how to avoid that?

Comment: Can someone explain in layman's terms why XORing all the numbers would return the first unique number?

Comment: @JoJo: it does not. But if you assume that the the array contains some numbers twice, and only one number once, and nothing else, it works... So, it works for e.g. (3,3,1,5,5) because 3^3^1^5^5=(3^3)^1^(5^5)=0^1^0=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSCountedSet* set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [set countForObject:obj] == 1;
}];
return index == NSNotFound ? nil : [array objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: Yes. `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:` enumerates the array in order and stops at the first which passes the test.

Comment: that's a good solution. i wrote a function that does the same thing, and it turns out that the `NSCountedSet` solution is about 20% faster than a hand-written solution.

Comment: This works great, I tested most of the cases I could come up with and works perfect..

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be reduced to [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), so there is no linear time solution, without using hashing and extra space.

One simple solution in O(n) time on average + space is:

1. Build a hash based histogram of the data, that maps each value to the number of its occurances.
2. Find the first number in the array that its value in the histogram is 1.

Pseudo code:

```
map = new hashmap
for each element x:
   if map contains x is a key:
       map.put(x,map.get(x)+1)
   else:
       map.put(x,1)
for each element x in array:
   if map.get(x) == 1:
       return x
//if reached here - no distinct element
```

**Example:**

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
create histogram: {[2=2] [3=2], [4=1]}
iterate the array:
   check 2, it has value of 2 in histogram. continue
   check 3, it has value of 2 in histogram. continue
   check 4, it has value of 1 in histogram. Return it and finish.
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't provide the *first* unique number, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, it does. Why do you claim it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I see that it does. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSNumber *)returnFirstUniqueFromArray: (NSArray *)array{

    //put the numbers in a set
    NSCountedSet *numbers = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
    for(NSNumber *number in array){
        //if it only occurs once return
        if([numbers countForObject:number]==1) return number;
    }

    return nil;

}
```

They key being here you need a good way to keep track of how many times something occurs so take advantage of NSCountedSet's "count" method. Will tell you how many times an object occurs.